# Spring FatalBeanException exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I start working on older Spring application and when I start it, it produces such log messages (~100 messages):

> 2015-02-10 15:53:11,757 INFO 
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:510]
>   - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@50533643:
>   startup date [Tue Feb 10 15:53:11 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy

And terminates with this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException

I am running it in IntelliJ IDEA and I use Maven for dependency management.

It never happed before - what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check your artifact configuration? Some libs may be outdated and / or not in the output layout.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to build it again with maven and build a new IDEA project. This problem is a dependency issue.

To build:

```
mvn clean install
```

and to create new IDEA project

```
mvn idea:clean idea:idea
```

Comment: It didn't help, the same problem.